# How to increase block time in a fork of Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, block-interval, node-discovery

I have questions about blocktime, please answer the ones you can. Help very appreciated!

Do you know if it is possible for ethereum forks to increase the 15s block time to for instance 1 min block time or 2 minutes block time?
Moreover I noticied that when we start new blockchain the miner can find blocks much quicker than 15s, so I assume it is linked to the difficulty in genesis.json. How much time should it take for a new blockchain to reach its actual block time? For instance in Bitcoin difficulty is adjusted every two weeks.
Is there another field than difficulty we can fill in genesis.json to influence block time? Is the difficulty in genesis.json just used as a starting point or is it used for the whole blockchain life?
Is the 15s blocktime set somewhere in the source code as a parameter and is it possible to set it to 1min or 2 mins?
Do you see unexpected possible problems for an ethereum fork with block time of 1 min or 2 mins?

Thank you very much!!!